# Include App liquid in shopify theme with GastbyJS + Storefront API

Tags: reactjs, shopify, liquid, storefront

I'm currently building a Shopify site with Gatsby and trying to implement a subscription with the Shopify App (Paywhirl).
According to the instructions, I need to INCLUDE the liquid provided by the Paywhirl App in the theme.

Snippet example is below.

`{% include 'paywhirl-subscriptions-cart-selling-plans', item: item %}`

We can insert liquid variables in modules like react-liquid, but is there a way to include Liquid in React?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a detailed description of the problem, _your own attempt_ at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. I hope you have a good time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build an eCommerce store with the headless approach and Shopify then there is a common issue regarding the APP integration, default liquid integration is not working anymore, you need to check the API's from APP developers and use the same in your headless approach.[img-link](https://prnt.sc/wbz6jh)

Here is the article regarding the same issue mentioned in the headless approach [Read More](https://iliashaddad.medium.com/convert-any-shopify-store-to-a-blazing-fast-website-with-gatsby-js-bfd610b03bc1)

Comment: I see. Paywhirl doesn't seem to provide its own API, so let's check out the Bold and Recharge APIs.
Thank you for answer!